# CUDA Nsight on OS X failing to make

Tags: macos, cuda, makefile, clang, nsight

I am attempting to `make` in Nsight IDE but unfortunately without any luck:

```
Building file: ../src/Cuda_Test.cu
Invoking: NVCC Compiler
/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-5.5/bin/nvcc -O3 -gencode arch=compute_12,code=sm_12 -odir "src" -M -o "src/Cuda_Test.d" "../src/Cuda_Test.cu"
clang: error: unsupported option '-dumpspecs'
clang: error: no input files
make: *** [src/Cuda_Test.o] Error 1
```

As i can understand on following pages:

http://blog.cryptohaze.com/2012/12/nvcc-os-x-clang-and-dumpspecs.html
http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-ports/2011-December/071844.html

It seems that i am using the wrong C and CPP compiler, but how can i change these parameters? The workaround seems to be valid for `CMake` and not `Make`.

```
usr/bin/gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.76) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.4.0
Thread model: posix
```

Environment:

```
echo $PATH
/usr/local/homebrew/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-5.5/bin

echo $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-5.5/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: Did you follow the mac [getting started guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-mac-os-x/index.html)?

Comment: @RobertCrovella, i have followed exactly that HOWTO..

Comment: So what were the results?  For example, in section 2.5.2 you are instructed to build the examples.  Was that successful?  In section 2.5.3 you're instructed to run some binaries, was that successful?

Comment: @RobertCrovella, things go wrong in `2.5.2` where i have to `make` as i explained in this post. I have found a thread concerning this issue which i am trying to fix https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/608127/clang-error-on-os-x-10-8-5-samples-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a workaround which obviously works in OS X 10.8.4. 
Simply used clang instead of g++ by adding following flag to nvcc: `nvcc -ccbin=/usr/bin/clang`

Reference: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/608127/clang-error-on-os-x-10-8-5-samples-/

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add that (while JavaCake pointed out the correct solution) the flag has to be set at both: the compiler stage and the linking stage.

To add the option open Project->Properties->Build->Settings->Tool Settings

- For the compiler select NVCC Compiler->Build Stages and enter `/usr/bin/clang` at compiler path.
- For the linker select NVCC Linker and add `-ccbin /usr/bin/clang` to the command.

(I did not yet find a global setting).